# Inheritance with templates shadows inherited member

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

I'm having the weirdest error and I've no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
template <bool X>
struct A {
    int x;
};

template <bool X>
struct B : public A<X> {
    B() { x = 3; } // Error: 'x' was not declared in this scope.
};
```

I don't understand how it's possible that I cannot see `x` from `B`, given that I'm inheriting `A` publicly.

At the same time, this code compiles:

```
template <bool X>
struct A {
    int x;
};

template <bool X>
struct B : public A<X> {};

int main() {
    B<false> b;
    b.x = 4;
};
```

I'm compiling with g++ 7.0.1.

Edit: It seems that if I reference the full-name of `x`, the code compiles, as in:

```
B() { A<X>::x = 3; }
```

But why?

Comment: Not that it helps, but MSVC has an extension that compiles this. :o

Comment: MSVC was always single pass. They **JUST** changed that to be compliant with the standard. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/09/11/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/

Comment: MSVC does produce an error if I turn off the language extensions. So at least compliant behavior is available.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't know how to find `x`. Use `this->X` and it will work.

At the time the compiler is doing its first pass over `struct B`, the template parameter is not known. By using the `this` pointer, you are deferring the name lookup until the second pass.

Comment: Ahh, right, I forgot about this. Dumb question, I know. Thanks.